# How to set up a persistent shopping cart in woocommerce for Multiple Devices and Browsers?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart, persistent, multiple-browsers

How can we setup persistent shopping cart in woocommerce for different devices.
Like if we login and add some products in cart and update cart then products in cart store in database and when I login from other device it fetches same data.
Right now it fetches data bases on user session. When we try to add products in cart in different browser it shows different products in cart in both browsers for same user.

Comment: I also have a same problem...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325626/save-cart-on-the-current-session

Comment: It would be very nice feature to rely on! Perhaps you should consider posting it to WooCommerce Ideas's Forum - http://ideas.woocommerce.com/forums/133476-woocommerce