# Woocommerce Cart Issue when same user added product from different browser

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the woocommerce plugin for shopping site in wordpress and there is an issue in that when i am login in a different different browser(Mozilla, Crome) and add products in cart than crome is not showing the products that are added form Mozilla  by the same user.

Comment: This is a common behavior... ressources are not shared between browsers... If you want this you'll have to overwrite all the cart saving system, and store it on database (maybe ?) with user_id... Is this important for you ? As a user, I would say "Ow, ok, my bad, I shouldn't use 2 browser at the same time"...

Comment: This is my client requirement...

Comment: So your duty is to convince him not to do this. You may try the same behavior on well-known e-commerce websites, and see they didn't implement this. This is a lot of work, since you have to rewrite a lot of stuff. If he wants it, he'll have to pay a high price (if he is only worried about price). It's easier to reuse what you got, than rewrite it... For instance, when I connect to facebook, I have 2 accounts, and I use different browsers for each account. I don't want browsers to share login informations...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325626/save-cart-on-the-current-session