# Is there a way to have different data in cart and checkout woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart, custom-wordpress-pages

I wanted to have different data in checkout and cart. means, when someone clicked a product directly to checkout, moves just the product to checkout without items that are in the cart.

or preventing the cart from going empty after checkout payment done
or is there a way to have multiple carts with all functionality on a site?

Comment: This may give you some light on how sessions work - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325626/save-cart-on-the-current-session . With the current question its unclear what you want to achieve but in short yes you can save cart sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes there is a solution using woocommerce sessions**

```
function temp_cart_session()
{
    WC()->session = new WC_Session_Handler();
    WC()->session->init();
    $session = WC()->session;
    if ($session->get('temp_cart')) {
        if ($session->get('temp_cart') instanceof WC_Cart) {
            $temp_cart = $session->get('temp_cart');
        } else {
            $temp_cart = new WC_Cart();
            $session->set('temp_cart', $temp_cart);
        }
    } else {
        $temp_cart = new WC_Cart();
        $session->set('temp_cart', $temp_cart);
    }
    return $temp_cart;
}
```

then we can use it with main cart functions